# synchrozing firebase database access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've one firebase database instance and I would like to add a counter to a certain node.

Everytime the users run an specific action I would like to increment the node value. How to do that without getting synchronization problems? How to use google functions to do that?

Ex.:

```
database{
node {
counter : 0
}

}
```

At certain time 3 different users read the value on counter, and try to increment it. As they read at exact same time all of them read "0" and incremented to "1", but the desired value at end of execution should be "3" since it was read 3 times

==================update===================

@renaud pointed to use transactions to keep synchronization on of the saved data, but i have another scenario where i need the synchronization done on read side also:

ex.
the user read the actual value, acording to it does a different action and finishing by incrementing one...

in a sql like enviorement i would write a procedure for doing that, because doesn't matter what user will do with the info i will finish always by incrementing one

If i did understand @renaud answer right, in that scenario 4 different users reading the database at same time would get 0 as current value, then on transaction update the final stored value would be 4, but on client side each of them just read 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a Transaction in this case, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions and also https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

A Transaction will "ensure there are no conflicts with other clients writing to the same location at the same time."

In a Cloud Function you could write your code along the following lines, for example:

```
....
const counterRef = admin
  .database()
  .ref('/node/counter');

return counterRef
  .transaction(current_value => {
    return (current_value || 0) + 1;
  })
  .then(counterValue => {
    if (counterValue.committed) {
      //For example update another node in the database 
      const updates = {};
      updates['/nbrOfActionsExecuted'] = counterValue.snapshot.val();
      return admin
        .database()
        .ref()
        .update(updates);
    }
  })
```

or simply the following if you just want to update the counter (Since a transaction returns a Promise, as explained in the second link referred to above):

```
exports.testTransaction = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const counterRef = admin
    .database()
    .ref('/node/counter');

  return counterRef
    .transaction(current_value => {
      return (current_value || 0) + 1;
    });
});
```

Note that, in this second case, I have used a Realtime Database trigger as an example of trigger.

Comment: i added some more details, please check

Comment: As explained in the doc "if another client writes to the location before your new value is successfully written, your update function is called again with the new current value, and the write is retried." So normally for your case with 4 persons, when the first person write to the location (after he has read the value), the ongoing transaction for the 3 other will be retried. to be continued...

Comment: ... continued.  In any case you have to take into account a/ the asynchronous character of the writing to the database and 2/ the fact that there may be a delay for triggering the Cloud Function. Note that you could also update your counter directly from the client frontend, also by calling a transaction.